# Jquery click div tag to show another div text

Tags: jquery, toggle

I have one problem about jquery to show and hide the text when click div or p tag.

for example:

```
 <div class="title" style="background-color: Yellow; cursor: pointer">
         The League secretary and monitor ___ asked to make a speech at the meeting. 
        </div>

        <div id="cont" style="display: none">
        答案B. 注： 先从时态上考虑。这是过去发生的事情应用过去时，先排除A.，C.。本题易误选D，因为The League secretary and monitor 好象是两个人，但仔细辨别， monitor 前没有the，在英语中，当一人兼数职时只在第一个职务前加定冠词。后面的职务用and 相连。这样本题主语为一个人，所以应选B。

        </div>
```

the js code:

```
        $(function () {
        $(".title").click(function () {
            $("#cont").toggle(200);
        });

    });
```

now the question is that, I have many line ,each line click the div.title, the show below div.cont.

```
  <div class="title_1" style="background-color: Yellow; cursor: pointer">
           title 1
        </div>

       <div id="cont_1" style="display: none">
       details 1 
          </div>

               <div class="title_2" style="background-color: Yellow; cursor: pointer">
           title 2
        </div>
          <div id="cont_2" style="display: none">
          details 2 
          </div>

               <div class="title_3" style="background-color: Yellow; cursor: pointer">
           title 3
        </div>
          <div id="cont_3" style="display: none">
          details 3
          </div>
           ........ may to title_50.
```

I don't want to use jquery search by id one by one, then the js code too long and not easy to maintain.

Can i use **$.each** something like that?

Any idea about this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use comman class `.title` for `all title divs`,and use **[next()](http://api.jquery.com/next/)** in jquery

```
   $(function () {
        $(".title").click(function () {
            $(this).next().toggle(200);
        });

    });
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/obax02zr/)**

Comment: For further specificity (if dom was to change) using siblings with a selector.

Answer (score 1):

Use common class names , not unique ones and you can use a traverse method like `next()`

```
$(".title").click(function () {
    $(this).next().toggle(200);
});
```

Reference: [**next() API Docs**](http://api.jquery.com/next/)